# png image transparent space covering anchors below it?

Tags: html, css

I am making this design
http://postimg.org/image/z0w6wb4zb/

I'm planing to make lots of animations and transitions so I inserted each layer separately (The island, each cloud on its own, each button), mostly as images, I couldn't remake any of these elements using css.

So, the problem is the island -as you can see- should be above the buttons. But when the z-index of the island is bigger than the buttons, the buttons are still visible but I can't hover/click them any more. As if the buttons are being covered by the island's transparent area.

What would be the recommended fix in this case?

Comment: Maybe you could place invisible buttons over the island, that represent the actual buttons?

Comment: `z-index` works with positioned elements. did you set position to them?

Answer (score 1):

You're right-- elements in html take up a rectangular space so regardless of the transparency of the background image, the transparent parts will still block what's below them. I can think of two solutions:

1. Split the island into two parts (narrow vertical one for the tree, and wider one for the ground). This is probably easier.
2. Add extra elements with absolute positioning that lines up with the buttons with a higher z-index. So, z-index of the buttons' images would be 1, on the island/tree would be 2, and on the invisible, clickable element above the buttons would be 3.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it didn't work? Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SBT2/) works well. Did you `position:absolute`? 
In that case as you said your island layer must a bigger div which hides the button divs.

Why don't you slice them a little since they are images and arrange them together so the divs won't cross each other, here is a [raw idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKLRD.jpg)...